# Android emulate touch on the screen using the joypad

Tags: android, touch, emulation, joypad

I'm trying to make and app that can emulate the touch on the screen using the controller i want to try to do something like this:
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller".
I'll use a wired xbox 360 controller.
I have the root access.

But i don't need to use the analog stick only the arrows and the button.
Android is new for me but I The program in java by a year.